About the growth rate of the balanced growth path
I found the following excersise with solution but without explanation. Hence I don't understand it.
Let $Y=BK^0E^{0.2}L^{0.8}$ be the production function. The growth rate of B is given by $g=0.2$
, of $L$ is given by $n=0.2$
and of $K$ is given by $0$. At first we assume that $E$ is generated by a stock
of non renewable resources $R$ such that $E=0.1R$. Calculate he growth rate along the balanced growth path.
Solution: 0.14 .
